# How can I get Youtube / Adobe flash player to use a my NVidia ION to offload video rendering in Windows 7 x64?

Tags: windows-7, adobe-flash, nvidia-ion

I've got Windows 7 Home Premium x64 running on an Acer Aspire r3700 with 2GB of RAM. I can play youtube videos up to 720p and they look great but I go as high as 1080p they start geting really jumpy.

Previously I'd always assumed it was a bandwidth issue but we've recently had BT Infinity installed and it's still laggy. Even when the video is buffered right the way to the end of the clip.

This prompted me to do some research. There seems to be a number of videos on youtube which indicate that Adobe flash player 10.1 and 10.2 should have enabled hardware decoding on the ION chipset. If I load up [a high-def youtube video](http://www.youtube.com/watch?v=GUEZCxBcM78) and go to video info it clearly states it's using a software renderer (note that it *does* mention hardware accelerated decoding):

[image: Software renderer enabled]

If I go to the options in adobe flash player it seems to think it's enabled:

[image]

I've tried updating my graphics drivers to the latest on the NVidia site (301.42 right now) but that made no difference. I'm using Chrome which is using Adobe Flash player v11.3.300.257

**Is there anything else I can do or is this as good as it gets?**

Answer (score 0, accepted):

D'oh! Can't believe I didn't spot this before. If you make the video full-screen it seems to enable full hardware decoding of video playback:

[image]

No frames dropped just super smooth playback :-)